# What's the difference between "Reaching For The Goal" and "Reaching To The Goal"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I'm asked to make a title for an article that's basically boiled down into either "Reaching For The Goal" or "Reaching To The Goal". I don't know what's the difference of them. I tried to google it, and "Reaching For The Goal" gets 5 million hits while "Reaching To The Goal" only gets 50 hits. So I guess "Reaching For The Goal" is more commonly used? But I still feel these two phrase interchangeably and both sounds right to me. Which one I should actually use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use "reach for the goal," as that's what native English speakers use. "For" here is used to indicate an intended goal, a function that "to" doesn't completely share in this context. "Reach to the goal" *might* work if the reaching isn't metaphorical -- that is, if there's actually a physical goal (like in sports) that the person is literally reaching towards -- but even in that case, "towards" would be more natural than "to," and "for" would still be appropriate. "For" is simply the preposition that native English speakers use with "reach" in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Ah, "towards" is an interesting alternative in this case. But I think I'll still stick to "for" then. Thanks!!